# SwiftUI - multiple levels deep NavigationLink does not work

Tags: swift, swiftui, view, navigation, swiftui-navigationlink

So I thought I found a way to make navigation in SwiftUI flexible and loosely coupled, yet still state-based and somewhat free of imperative-navigation bugs (double push, etc).

Basic idea is to have a linked list of Views (erased to AnyView) and a recursive view with NavigationLink in it, which is active when corresponding view is present in the list

But it does not work and I don't understand why. On iOS device it only pushes one level deep, even though the list is multiple levels deep and the bindings return true

Is it a SwiftUI bug or am I missing something?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State
    var navigationList: NavigationList?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Navigatable(list: $navigationList) {
                Button("Push test", action: {
                    navigationList = .init(next: nil, screen: Screen {
                        TestView()
                    })
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    @Environment(\.navigationList)
    @Binding
    var list
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Push me", action: {
            list = .init(next: nil, screen: Screen {
                TestView()
            })
        })
    }
}

struct Navigatable<Content: View>: View {
    @Binding
    var list: NavigationList?
    let content: () -> Content

    init(list: Binding<NavigationList?>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self._list = list
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            NavigationLink(
                isActive: isActive,
                destination: {
                    Navigatable<Screen?>(list: childBinding) {
                        list?.screen
                    }
                }, 
                label: EmptyView.init
            ).hidden()
            LazyView {
                content()
            }.environment(\.navigationList, $list)
        }
    }
    
    var isActive: Binding<Bool> {
        .init(
            get: { list != nil },
            set: {
                if !$0 {
                    list = nil
                }
            }
        )
    }
    
    var childBinding: Binding<NavigationList?> {
        .init(
            get: { list?.next },
            set: { list?.next = $0 }
        )
    }
}

struct Screen: View {
    let content: () -> AnyView
    
    init<C: View>(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> C) {
        self.content = {
            .init(content())
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        content()
    }
}

struct NavigationList {
    @Indirect
    var next: NavigationList?
    
    let screen: Screen
}


enum NavigationListKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static var defaultValue: Binding<NavigationList?> {
        .constant(nil)
    }
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var navigationList: Binding<NavigationList?> {
        get { self[NavigationListKey.self] }
        set { self[NavigationListKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

struct LazyView<Content: View>: View {
    @ViewBuilder var content: () -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        content()
    }
}

@propertyWrapper
struct Indirect<Wrapped> {
    private final class Storage: CustomReflectable {
        var wrapped: Wrapped
        
        init(_ wrapped: Wrapped) {
            self.wrapped = wrapped
        }
        
        var customMirror: Mirror {
            .init(self, children: [(label: "wrapped", value: wrapped)])
        }
    }
    
    private let storage: Storage
    
    var wrappedValue: Wrapped {
        get { storage.wrapped }
        mutating set { storage.wrapped = newValue }
    }
    
    init(wrappedValue: Wrapped) {
        self.storage = .init(wrappedValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. the minimal code should be in the question not linked

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: On iOS device it pushes only one screen

Answer (score 0):

You’re missing `isDetailLink(false)` which is what allows multiple screens to be pushed on to one navigation controller.

But there are also structural problems with the code. It's best to use SwiftUI View data structs as designed and let them store the hierachy of data. If you go off on your own architecture then you lose the magic like invalidation and diffing and it'll likely slow down too.

Comment: Unfortunately is does not solve the problem

Comment: I’m not surprised,  that SwiftUI code is very weird.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on how to improve it?

Comment: Just use SwiftUI View data structs as designed, as small as possible. No fancy patterns are required.